# showing only every <n> dates on x-axis (or grouping by month) to reduce x-axis clutter

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I am currently learning some Python by using Jupyter Notebook and matplotlib library to produce some graphs from JSON data. I've been able to produce charts which is great, but I'm not sure how to de-clutter my x-axis. See below screenshot. There is a value for each day, and there are hundreds of days in the data passed in. This creates a very cluttered x-axis that's unreadable.

Code:

```
dates = [i['daily_sales_date'] for i in json_data]
values = [i['daily_sales'] for i in json_data]
print('sample date: ' + dates[0])
print('sample value: ' + str(values[0]))
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'values':values})
df['dates']  = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in df['dates']]
plt.bar(dates, values)
```

Result:

[image]

That thick black bar, is all my dates :). I have tried reviewing some examples that supposedly un-clutter the x-axis dates, but I haven't gotten them to work. I woul be happy to either show only a subset of dates along the axis, or even just show the month names. The best I can do is causing the x-axis labels not to show up at all :/ Any advice?

[image]

I have attempted the following as per one of the suggestions:

```
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator
register_matplotlib_converters()
```

Then to create the graph:

[image]

As you can see, I now get 2019 (the year) but no months? Sample data included below for clarity (at request)

```
[
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-10T13:10:00.6",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4994.2,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-10T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-09T23:00:01.213",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8868.75,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-09T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-08T23:00:02.093",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4618.55,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-08T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-07T23:00:01.52",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5710.01,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-07T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-06T23:00:01.42",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9674.46,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-06T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-05T23:50:01.977",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9243.66,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-05T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-04T23:50:01.5",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8865.75,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-04T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-03T23:00:01.003",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5530.14,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-03T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-02T23:00:01.71",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4893.77,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-01T23:00:01.61",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 3741.6,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-31T23:00:00.893",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8727.52,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-31T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-30T23:00:01.263",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9572.48,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-30T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-29T23:50:01.937",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 20003.71,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-29T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-28T23:50:00.933",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 29890.54,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-28T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-27T23:00:01.267",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 19669.24,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-27T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-26T23:00:13.68",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 18655.44,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-26T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-25T23:00:12.427",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4876.38,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-25T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-24T23:00:16.313",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8467.17,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-23T23:00:23.517",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 12542.34,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-23T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-22T23:50:14.363",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 12119.07,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-22T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-21T23:50:12.527",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9403.31,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-21T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-20T23:00:15.797",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5872.87,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-20T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-19T23:10:09.547",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4634.91,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-19T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-18T23:00:10.887",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5789.16,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-18T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-17T23:00:07.93",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9743.17,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-17T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-16T23:00:12.367",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 10729.08,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-16T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-15T23:50:09.177",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9404.83,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-15T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-14T23:50:11.423",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9029.93,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-14T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-13T23:00:17.653",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4464.14,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-13T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-12T23:00:14.063",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4711.15,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-12T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-11T23:00:11.227",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 7090.3,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-11T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-10T23:00:07.127",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8083.23,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-10T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-09T23:10:10.253",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 10253.7,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-09T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-08T23:50:09.863",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 12339.06,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-08T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-07T23:50:10.497",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 10200.52,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-07T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-06T23:10:10.87",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 6694.55,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-06T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-05T23:10:08.707",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5779.48,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-05T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-04T23:00:09.39",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4954.72,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-04T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-03T23:00:10.75",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8473.28,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-03T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-02T23:00:09.637",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 11327.68,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-02T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-01T23:50:11.49",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 11075.8,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-28T23:50:10.217",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9143.1,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-28T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-27T23:00:09.44",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5523.66,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-27T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-26T23:00:08.913",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5235.5,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-26T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-25T23:00:19.74",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5379.84,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-25T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-24T23:00:09.44",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 7194.78,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-23T23:00:11.783",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9438.9,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-23T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-22T23:50:07.167",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9989.46,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-22T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-21T23:50:06.98",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 10120.73,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-21T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-20T23:00:14.46",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5732.03,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-20T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main and only problem is that the "dates" are strings. If you convert your strings to dates the plot will look as expected. You are doing that already inside the dataframe, but then do not use that column in any of the further code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'values':values})
df['dates']  = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])  # possibly format="..."
plt.bar(df['dates'].values, df['values'].values)
```

```css
# The complete example would be:

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

json_data = [
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-10T13:10:00.6",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4994.2,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-10T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-09T23:00:01.213",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8868.75,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-09T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-08T23:00:02.093",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4618.55,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-08T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-07T23:00:01.52",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5710.01,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-07T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-06T23:00:01.42",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9674.46,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-06T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-05T23:50:01.977",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9243.66,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-05T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-04T23:50:01.5",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8865.75,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-04T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-03T23:00:01.003",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5530.14,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-03T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-02T23:00:01.71",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4893.77,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-04-01T23:00:01.61",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 3741.6,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-31T23:00:00.893",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8727.52,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-31T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-30T23:00:01.263",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9572.48,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-30T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-29T23:50:01.937",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 20003.71,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-29T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-28T23:50:00.933",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 29890.54,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-28T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-27T23:00:01.267",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 19669.24,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-27T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-26T23:00:13.68",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 18655.44,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-26T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-25T23:00:12.427",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4876.38,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-25T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-24T23:00:16.313",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8467.17,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-23T23:00:23.517",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 12542.34,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-23T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-22T23:50:14.363",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 12119.07,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-22T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-21T23:50:12.527",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9403.31,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-21T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-20T23:00:15.797",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5872.87,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-20T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-19T23:10:09.547",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4634.91,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-19T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-18T23:00:10.887",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5789.16,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-18T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-17T23:00:07.93",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9743.17,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-17T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-16T23:00:12.367",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 10729.08,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-16T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-15T23:50:09.177",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9404.83,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-15T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-14T23:50:11.423",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9029.93,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-14T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-13T23:00:17.653",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4464.14,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-13T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-12T23:00:14.063",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4711.15,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-12T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-11T23:00:11.227",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 7090.3,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-11T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-10T23:00:07.127",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8083.23,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-10T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-09T23:10:10.253",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 10253.7,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-09T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-08T23:50:09.863",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 12339.06,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-08T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-07T23:50:10.497",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 10200.52,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-07T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-06T23:10:10.87",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 6694.55,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-06T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-05T23:10:08.707",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5779.48,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-05T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-04T23:00:09.39",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 4954.72,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-04T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-03T23:00:10.75",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 8473.28,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-03T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-02T23:00:09.637",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 11327.68,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-02T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-03-01T23:50:11.49",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 11075.8,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-03-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-28T23:50:10.217",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9143.1,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-28T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-27T23:00:09.44",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5523.66,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-27T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-26T23:00:08.913",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5235.5,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-26T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-25T23:00:19.74",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5379.84,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-25T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-24T23:00:09.44",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 7194.78,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-24T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-23T23:00:11.783",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9438.9,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-23T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-22T23:50:07.167",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 9989.46,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-22T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-21T23:50:06.98",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 10120.73,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-21T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "RowInsertDateTime": "2019-02-20T23:00:14.46",
        "ServerName": "P781S001",
        "StoreName": "PRICELINE WERRIBEE",
        "daily_sales": 5732.03,
        "daily_sales_date": "2019-02-20T00:00:00"
    }
]

dates = [i['daily_sales_date'] for i in json_data]
values = [i['daily_sales'] for i in json_data]
print('sample date: ' + dates[0])
print('sample value: ' + str(values[0]))

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'values':values})
df['dates']  = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])  # possibly format="..."
plt.bar(df['dates'].values, df['values'].values)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code so that now I don't get the 'glut' of dates all smooshed together, but there are still too many dates showing. Have tried to use the monthlocator but without the expected results.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. But I don't think anyone can find out without [mcve].

Comment: By example do you mean the sample data? I have updated the question with this.

Comment: With the data given, it [looks fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlqif.png).

Comment: Have you adjusted the code at all from that within my example? As it doesn't render like that for me. I just get the year value. Sorry to be a pain, but could you perhaps show me the code block you've used to produce that?

Comment: Thanks - that works for me, however if I add the code to only show months (at least that's what i think it should do) it only shows the year label? dates = [i['daily_sales_date'] for i in json_data]
values = [i['daily_sales'] for i in json_data]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'values':values})
df['dates']  = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])  # possibly format="..."
plt.bar(df['dates'].values, df['values'].values)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
plt.show()   result: https://ibb.co/2SSJ0z4

Comment: Yes, that is probably expected, because you haven't set any `Formatter` to the axis.

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing my best bet here is to Google matplotlib and Formatter to understand the syntax to use this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can show only every n-th date to reduce the clutter:

```
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
n = len(ticks) // 10  # Show 10 ticks.
ax.set_xticks(ticks[::n])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels[::n])
```

Comment: I'd say this is the most elegant and general answer (also, none of the above worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

Use a *tick locator*:

```
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
```

This will create one tick for every month. See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator) for more customisation options.

Comment: Updated question with this attempt. As you can see I got the year showing now, but that's all?

Comment: @JamesMatson That's a little strange. It would help if you provided an exact sample of your data so that we can better answer your question.

Comment: I've updated the question with the sample data. I apologise for stealing your time to look at this, as a beginner with Python, Jupyter Notebooks and matplotlib it's 99% likely I'm doing something terribly stupid :/